# Getting error while creating PHP runtime using AWS env layer

Tags: php, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I want to create AWS Environment layer which can be used with Lambda function. Which will act as PHP Compiler. I feel that some network related setting blocking below command to execute. Please guid me for this.

I am trying to install guzzlehttp/guzzle but while installing I am getting below error

```
$ ./bin/php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.

In RequireCommand.php line 225:
                                                                                                                          
  No composer.json present in the current directory (./composer.json), this may be the cause of the following exception.  
                                                                                                                          

In CurlDownloader.php line 365:
                                                                                                          
  curl error 0 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: unsupported ALPN protocol: ''  
                                                                                                          

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
```

Then I created below is my composer.json file, then still getting second error

> curl error 0 while downloading
> https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: unsupported ALPN protocol:
> ''

```
{
            "require": {
                            "php": ">=7.3"
            },
            "repositories": [
                   {
                        "packagist": false
                   },
                   {
                           "type": "composer",
                           "url": "https://packagist.org"
                   }
            ]
}
```

PHP version which I compiled is below:

```
PHP 7.3.0 (cli) (built: May 20 2023 04:13:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Can anyone help me solve this error?

I am using below article to create custom runtime for PHP.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/

Comment: What is the output when you run `curl -vvv https://packagist.org/packages.json` into the run instance?

Comment: Why do you have `"packagist": false`, do you have the intent to ignore packagist.org on composer install?

Comment: Where do you run `composer require`? Shouldn't that happen on your development machine, and not anywhere on AWS?